# Spinnaker Gate is redirecting to the incorrect authentication URL

Tags: redirect, groovy, spinnaker

So I have spinnaker running behind an https load balancer and my external ports use the standard 443 which get port mapped to the spinnaker instance still on port 9000. I've gotten pretty much everything to work except a redirect from gate is still appending the :9000 port to my URL.

requests sent to `https://my.url.com/gate/auth/redirect?to=https://my.url.com/#/infrastructure` send back a redirect response with the location header in the 301 `location:https://my.url.com:9000/gate/login` which fails because the load balancer is only listening for 443. If I manually delete the port and go right to `https://my.url.com/gate/login` the oauth flow works as expected and once authed all deck functionality and subsequent gate queries work as expected.

In my /etc/default/spinnaker file I have

```
SPINNAKER_DECK_BASEURL=https://my.url.com
SPINNAKER_GATE_BASEURL=https://my.url.com/gate
```

in /opt/spinnaker/config/gate-googleOAuth.yml I have

```
spring:
 oauth2:
   client:
     preEstablishedRedirectUri: ${SPINNAKER_GATE_BASEURL}/login
     useCurrentUri: false
```

and I've ran `/opt/spinnaker/bin/reconfigure_spinnaker.sh` plus restarts to make sure deck and gate get updated. Does anyone have any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem. With the help of this issue pointing me in the right direction (https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/1112) and some digging I found that the issue was with apache2 and the reverse proxy back to gate.

```
ProxyPassReverse

This directive lets Apache httpd adjust the URL in the Location, Content-Location 
and URI headers on HTTP redirect responses. This is essential when Apache httpd
is used as a reverse proxy (or gateway) to avoid bypassing the reverse proxy because
of HTTP redirects on the backend servers which stay behind the reverse proxy.
```

from apache2 documentation https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse